# Connect Hadoop+Hive with MongoDB on AWS EMR (class not found com/mongodb/DBObject)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, mongodb-java, emr

I like to connect an EMR Cluster to our MongoDB via an MongoDB Connection (not via BSON Dumps).

For that i spawned the cluster over the AWS Management Console. On the Bootstrap configuration I pointed to this file which is placed on S3:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -P /home/hadoop/lib http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.0/mongo-java-driver-2.13.0.jar

wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2.jar
wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-pig-1.3.2.jar
wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.2.jar
```

When the cluster is spawned I sshed into the master and saw that they are successfully downloaded.

When I exectue this in the Hive shell:

```
CREATE TABLE nicks
( 
  id STRING,
  name STRING,
  business STRING,
  alias STRING
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://54.93.123.123:27017/foo.aliases');

ADD JAR /home/hadoop/lib/mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2.jar;
ADD JAR /home/hadoop/lib/mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.2.jar;
ADD JAR /home/hadoop/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.13.0.jar;

Select * from nicks;
```

I get this exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitterByClass(MongoSplitterFactory.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoSplitterFactory.getSplitter(MongoSplitterFactory.java:109)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getSplits(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat.getSplits(HiveMongoInputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:636)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.DBObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 20 more
```

**Note:**

- I haved (with ssh) that all the 4 libs are placed in the correct folder
- Mongo-Hive connector JAR seems to be loaded because I got another exception before that was fixed by executing "ADD JAR ...".
- I checked the contents of the mongo-java-driver jar. It seems to be valid (i found the DBObject class inside)

How to fix that or how can i debug whats wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to put the libs also into `/home/hadoop/hive/lib`. With this script it works:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -P /home/hadoop/lib http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.0/mongo-java-driver-2.13.0.jar

wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2.jar
wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-pig-1.3.2.jar
wget -P /home/hadoop/lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.3.2/mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.2.jar

cp /home/hadoop/lib/mongo* /home/hadoop/hive/lib
```